# first-order differential equation problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given that $y=\sin(x)$ is an expicit function of the first-order differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{1-y^2}$. Find an interval I of definition, the solution interval.

So I got to the point that $\cos(x)={\cos(x)}$, what do I do next?

Comment: For what values of $x$ is $\cos x = \sqrt{1 - \sin^2 x}$? This is not true for all real numbers $x$.

Comment: Oh okay, so there would be no interval, right?

Comment: No, think again.

Comment: what are the constant solutions of this differential equation?

Comment: @SimonS I really don't know. I just started this course.

Comment: This now isn't a question about differential equations. Think back to high school trig. If necessary draw the graphs of $\cos x$ and $\sqrt{1 - \sin^2 x}$; when do they overlap? Certainly not for $\cos x < 0$.

Comment: It would be only the ones above the x-axis since it is in absolute value

Comment: @SimonS Am I right?

Comment: Specifically $[0,\pi/2]\cup[2\pi, 5\pi/2]\cup...$

Comment: @JuliaHall don't forget to try $y = \pm 1$...

Answer (score 0):

$\sqrt{1-\sin ^2 x}\geq 0$. Hence $\cos x \geq 0$ which requires $0\leq x\leq \pm \pi/2$.

Comment: How could ever $0\leq x \leq -\pi/2$?

Comment: That is a mistake. It is $0\leq |x| \leq \pi/2$. Thanks for pointing out.